# Any ways of referencing javascript project in a c# project for windows store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winjs

Is there way to reference or open a page in the windows store app built using javascript template from a C# project template?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question

Answer (score 1):

UI from C# and JavaScript apps aren't able to interact with one another directly on the project level. Although you can create a Windows Runtime Component in C# or C++ and use it from a JavaScript app, there still isn't the ability to share UI.

The only want to host HTML/CSS/JS in a C# app is through a webview control. You can interact with the JavaScript in the webview via its InvokeScriptAsync method, and the JS can raise events through window.external.notify, but the JS won't have access to the WinRT APIs like a JavaScript app does.

One app can launch another, of course, through either file or protocol association, but that's a different matter than building different parts of a single app with different technologies. Within that scope, a JS app can again use non-UI WinRT components, and a C# app can host a webview. Those are really the options.